# Why Boolean.class is java.lang.Class and String.class is java.lang.String?

Tags: java, android, generics

I'm trying to implement a generic method with input type specified (errm.. *dirty-hacked*) by `Class<T>`.

```
public static <T> T getSecure(Class<T> type, String name, T def, ....)
```

When requested as:

```
getSecure(String.class, "foo", "", ....);
```

It can be found that `type == String.class`, `type.getClass().toString().compareTo(String.class.toString()) == 0)`.

However, `type == boolean.class || type == Boolean.class` is always false for any incoming arguments.

Comment: I don't understand your question/problem. It seems like you are comparing two different things.

Comment: You really haven't given us enough information to go on. Please provide a short but complete program demonstrating the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why Boolean.class is java.lang.Class and String.class is
>   java.lang.String?

It isn't.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(Boolean.class);
    System.out.println(boolean.class);
}
```

prints

```
class java.lang.Boolean
boolean
```

as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing a compare by getting the class then making it a string (to get java.lang.String) to see if it is equal to the hardcoded string use instanceof like:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Object[] testData = {"", new Boolean(true), new Integer(2), new Long(3), true};

    for (Object object : testData) {
        typeCheck(object);
    }
}


private static void typeCheck(Object object) {
    StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
    b.append(object instanceof String).append(", ");
    b.append(object instanceof Boolean).append(", ");
    b.append(object instanceof Integer).append(", ");
    b.append(object instanceof Long);

    System.out.println("Testing: "+object.getClass().toString()+": "+b.toString());
}
```

Output:

Testing: class java.lang.String: true, false, false, false
Testing: class java.lang.Boolean: false, true, false, false
Testing: class java.lang.Integer: false, false, true, false
Testing: class java.lang.Long: false, false, false, true
Testing: class java.lang.Boolean: false, true, false, false